# ssrs group report expand-collapse in html render

Tags: ssrs-2008, ssrs-grouping

I created a ssrs report in a server and this report has row groups. 
My use in the report is through my website as i use the reportexecutionserivcesoap to render the report in HTML4.0 format.

I put the html result (after i set the parameters in my app server) in the website and the table looks good but the problem is that when i click the expand '+' icon of the group i get an error:  "This report requirea a default or user-defined value for the report parametrt".
I have read that the expand button sends a postback request to the report server so i assume that the postback request being sent without the parameters i already set.

What can i do so the parameter (wich i noticed that exists in the html result in  tags) will be sent to the report server in the postback request

Comment: You need to update your report and set the parameters in your  report.

Comment: Is your report drill-trough or drill down ?

Comment: Drill down report.  By the way when i render it to an excel file it is being rendered in the optimal way when all the data exists but hided and when i click '+' the data is shown